# Hibernate unable to use XML and Annotation Entities in tangent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am attempting to create a new hibernate entity using annotations within a legacy spring project. All of the previous existing entities were defined using `.hbm.xml` files. I am finding though that my new annotated entity is unable to make references to the legacy `.hbm` defined ones.

Since this is a spring project this was added into the `sessionFactory` bean in order to allow my new entity to be resolved by the session factory.

```
<property name="mappingResources" ref="mappingResources"/>
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.project"/>
```

In my new object I made a single reference to an old entity like this

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "oldEntityId")
private OldEntity old;
```

The old entity, which is picked up fine using the legacy method, is unable to be retrieved via hibernate from the new annotated entity.

Now when the entities are initialized this exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.project...NewEntity references an unknown entity: com.project...OldEntity
```

If I attempt to simply add an `@Entity` annotation to the `OldEntity`, that error is replaced with a duplicate entity message.

If there is anything which I may be missing here or what I am trying to accomplish is impossible please let me know.

Spring Ver: org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.14.RELEASE
Hibernate Ver: org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.7.Final

Edit:
Turns out if I use the old hbm.xml method everything works seamlessly. I am only having a problem with the annotated method.

Comment: Which Spring and Hibernate version are you using?

Comment: org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.14.RELEASE
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.7.Final

Comment: So 4.3.14 & 4.1.7.Final for those 2 @M.Deinum

Comment: Please add the version information to your question not as comments and please add both Spring and Hibernate versions. In theory combining XML and annotations should work (and it works because you get a duplicate entity exception).

Comment: Note taken!

Now is there something which could possibly be blocking the annotated entity from being able to view hbm configured entities or be able to make the @Entity tag on the OldEntity not cause a duplicate error but allow the Annotated one access it?